# Azure Get Video Index or Get Project Index API response body is blank

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

This is about Azure Video Indexer API. I am using a trial account. (Using Corporate account to log in to the Video Indexer portal but using a trial, not a paid account yet). I uploaded a few videos using Indexer Portal. Then I am trying to use the Video Indexer API to get video index. The Get Video Index (or Get Project Index) APIs give proper response when called through the "Try it" panel of the Developer Portal. But when exactly same Get API is called through Java code, the response is blank. The response status is 200 OK. Response header also shows valid header as follows:

[Content-Length:"13052", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", x-ms-request-id:"a747d33c-a1e8-444d-89ce-d49a531507c2", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", api-supported-versions:"2.0", Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:"true", Date:"Thu, 27 Oct 2022 15:19:53 GMT"]

But response body just doesnt print anything.

(Just to repeat, the same Get API call works fine from the "Try it" panel using same/similar access token etc. But when called through Java code, it doesnt give back any response, not any error).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have already tried using the readily available Java code snippet provided in the "Try it" panel. But same behaviour.

Thanks.
mrisbud

Comment: can you please elaborate more about what do you mean by `I have already tried using the readily available Java code snippet provided in the "Try it" panel. But same behavior`. Do you mean it is same behavior as working or non-working?

Also, can you try to capture network traces for a working and non-working trial and compare them?

Comment: Hi, 

Looking at Video Indexer logs the response was successful. It seems that there is a problem with the calling code. It is hard to assist if there is no code snippet of the how you send the request and response